# My layout gets messed up when I zoom in and out

Tags: html, css

I designed this page while taking reference `125%` zoom on my browser. But when I zoom out or zoom in, my layouts get messed up. The left column doesn't change, but other columns change.

Should I re-design this page? Or can we find a solution?

Someone says don't use `px` with `margin`, and I didn't.

I want to change the browser zoom level to `125%` except while using on `125%` zoom.

```js
zoom();

function zoom() {
  document.body.style.zoom = "125%" 
}
```

```css
-@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
  body {
      background-image: url(kupa/kupawall1.jpg);
      background-color: burlywood;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

  .buton {
    margin: 0.6cm;
    border-radius: 40%;
    background-color: aqua;
    border-style: double;
  }

  .buton2 {
    lighting-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 15%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .image {
    border-radius: 80%;
  }

  #baslık {
    padding-left: 40%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
  }

  #altBas {
    margin: 2%;
    font-size: 90%;
  }

  #kupaIcon {
    margin-left: -1%;
    margin-top: 0.3%;
  }

  #kupabuton {
    margin-top: 0.3%;
    margin-left: 0.8%;
  }

  #madalyabuton {
    margin-left: 20%;
  }

  #madalyaIcon {
    margin-top: -17%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }


  #porselenIcon {
    margin-left: 60%;
    margin-top: -17%;
  }

  #porselenButon {
    margin-left: 60.5%;
  }

  #kristalButon {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 40%;
  }

  #kristalicon {
    margin-top: -17.5%;
    margin-left: 39%;
  }

  #camicon {
    margin-left: 80%;
    margin-top: -17%;
  }

  #Ignebuton {
    margin-left: 31%;
  }

  #IgneIcon {
    margin-left: 30%;
  }

  #OzelIcon {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: -17.3%;
  }

  #Ozelbuton {
    margin-left: 9%;
  }

  .sayfaDuzen {
    margin-top: -9%;
  }

  #anahtarIcon {
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: -17%;
  }

  #anahtarButon {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }

  #rozetIcon {
    margin-left: 70%;
    margin-top: -17%;
  }

  #rozetButon {
    margin-left: 71%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:chocolate" id="baslık"><strong> AKTÜRK REKLAM</strong></h1>
<pre id="altBas"><b><em>SİZ HAYAL EDİN BİZ GERÇEKLEŞTİRELİM</em></b></pre>
<hr />

<a href=index.html>  <button class ="buton2" id="anasayfa">Anasayfa</button></a>
<a href=hakkımızda.html>  <button class ="buton2" id="anasayfa">Hakkımızda </button></a>
<a href=iletisim.html>  <button class ="buton2">İletişim</button></a>
<hr />

<!-- Should contain <li>'s, pointless use of <ul> -->
<ul>
  <br><br> <br><br> <br>

  <div class="sayfaDuzen">
    <a href="kupalar.html">
      <div id="kupaIcon">
        <img src="kupa/kupa15.jpg"  class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="kupabuton">
        <button class="buton">Ödüller</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="madalyalar.html">
      <div id="madalyaIcon">
        <img src="madalya/madIcon.jpg" class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="madalyabuton">
        <button class="buton">Madalyalar</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="porselenler.html">
      <div id="porselenIcon">
        <img src="porselen/plaketIcon.jpg" class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="porselenButon">
        <button class="buton">Plaketler</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="kristaller.html">
      <div id="kristalicon">
        <img src="Kristal/kristal1.jpg"  class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="kristalButon">
        <button class="buton">Kristaller</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="camlar.html">
      <div id="camicon">
        <img src="camlar/camicon.jpg"  class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
        <div id="cambuton"></div>
        <button class="buton">Camlar</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="ıgneler.html">
      <div id="IgneIcon">
        <img src="ıgneler/ıgneIcon.jpg" class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="Ignebuton">
        <button class="buton">İğneler</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="ozel.html">
      <div id="OzelIcon"><img src="ozelPDF/ozelIcon.jpg" class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="Ozelbuton">
        <button class="buton">Özel Madalyalar</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="anahtar.html">
      <div id="anahtarIcon">
        <img src="anahtarlık/anahIcon.jpg" class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="anahtarButon">
        <button class="buton">Anahtarlıklar</button>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="rozetler.html">
      <div id="rozetIcon">
        <img src="rozet/rozetIcon.jpg" class="image" width="130" height="130"/>
      </div>
      <div id="rozetButon">
        <button class="buton">Rozetler</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</ul>

<h6>content</h6>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "left column does not change, but other columns do"? To me it seems fine as it is unless you can explicitly explain what is going wrong.

Comment: @Barrosy afer I wrote this '<script type="text/javascript">
        function zoom() {
            document.body.style.zoom = "125%" 
        }
      </script>' if you use your browser in 100% zoom everything is okay. But when I change zoom to 125%. Layouts  get messed again. I don't want to run this code when I change zoom to 125%

Comment: You have to be more specific. "Layouts get messed"... What part of your layout "gets messed"? Maybe add an image of how it currently looks and what your desired layout should look like?

Comment: There's a lot of things going wrong with the HTML, missing closing tags and you are using a `<ul>` element without `<li>` elements inside, what would be the point there? I will try to update your code.

Comment: I updated your code within the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7ut02Ly/).

Comment: Updated [with CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/xgp6awe2/)

Comment: Using Margins is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Barrosy Thanks a lot, but still when I zoom in or zoom out everything get messed

Comment: What do you mean by "everything"? @MertArdaAsar

Comment: @Barrosy i think he means that his layout is not responsive. And he'd be right.

Comment: @Ari Yes, can I do this without design this page again?

Comment: You don't have to residesign everything, just rewrite your html and css and follow some tutorials about responsive websites.